Using pyenv python inplace of system default
I am on archlinux and trying to run krita scripter (built-in python console) with a pyenv python version. The system default python version is 3.12, however the script I am running uses python libraries that require version 3.11.
Here is what I have tried so far.

pyenv init, checked the version on console, it shows correct 3.11 (also tried setting pyenv global 3.11
Install pyqt5 package with pip - this installs the packages in site-packages of pyenv 3.11 but I am not sure if it also builds the correct binaries required (the ones  installed with the system package pacman -S python-pyqt5)
export PYTHONHOME=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11:$PYTHONPAH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Now if I run krita from console I get error

krita: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libKF5WidgetsAddons.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN11QToolButton13checkStateSetEv, version Qt_5

krita: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libKF5WidgetsAddons.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN11QToolButton13checkStateSetEv, version Qt_5
Then I did :
ldd /usr/lib/libKF5WidgetsAddons.so.5 | grep Qt
This shows ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 and other similar files.
so the so is found but looks like it's not compatible with libKF5WidgetsAddons.so (KDE qt5)?
How can I resolve this issue? Any other approach to simply replace default python with custom python in krita is also welcome. As a side note: I tried downloading the appimage of krita and it works fine with built-in 3.10 (this of course doesn't help, as I can't reinstall all the required libraries in this and repackage the appimage)

I check source code and it seems it doesn't use Python as external process (it doesn't run executable python which you can run in console) but it use it as embeded - it may have python's code inside its executable file or it may uses some library python.so and it can't use other version. It means It would need to compile C/C++  code again to replace Python version.

You need to rebuild Krita. See this and this.

@furas I checked, and krita does use system python if  installed via official package. Confirmed by installing libs in system python, which are picked up by scripter. I think only the appimage uses python.so

@relent95 Thanks! I think I will simply install the required package on system python (with --break-system-packages flag, this is much less of a trouble than compiling Krita, which I am horrified of :)

It's not recommended to do that. As you can see at the links I commented before, the pykrita extension was built upon the system python 3.12 headers and library. Try ldd /usr/lib/kritaplugins/kritapykrita.so |grep libpython

@relent95 similar information I found in source code :) In few places I saw #include <Python.h>
